# js code disappears after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, forms, joomla, submit, uniform

i use JSN Uniform for Joomla.
and add some styles with my scripts.js file .

```
$('input[type=file]').bootstrapFileInput();
$('.file-inputs').bootstrapFileInput();
$('input[type=file]').attr('data-filename-placement','inside');
```

but after submit - js code disappears.
my test site http://bolomsa.com/

Comment: Rather than using jQuery to apply styling, why not create a Template Override and manually add the classes required to the elements?

Comment: i need js for .bootstrapFileInput. css - is example